# What is the difference between "middleware" and "application server"?

Tags: webserver, middleware

Application servers like Weblogic and WebSphere are all used like middleware. What is the difference between these two concepts?

Answer (score 6):

Middleware is anything that is not part of an operating system,  and neither is it part of one software application, but rather lies between them.
Hence, Application Server is a type of Middleware.

Comment: +1 a simple statement such as "... Application Server is a type of Middleware." is so understated but so fundamental to what a middleware is/can be. There is a prominent misnomer that middleware always sits between client and app, i.e. in the middle, but the truth is that the app itself is a middleware and can be an endpoint in a pipeline. People tend to confuse/interchange middleware for gateways (a sort of business logic less pipe doorway rather than an endpoint service)

Answer (score 2):

[Middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware#Middleware_in_distributed_applications) is more general than Application Server.

An application server is one type of middleware.

The fact is that the term middleware, when applied to distributed computing is rather vague and can be applied to any piece of software that exists between the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Application Servers may also include components like Web/Servlet containers. Middleware is something that enables inter-system communication/data exchange.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding

> **Application Server** - Middlewares + your application
>
> **Middlewares** - It acts as a bridge between your request and
>   application. They process the requests and provides response in
>   an efficient way.

To make more clear, WebSphere is an application server written in Java and a middleware can be injected into it to make your request and response efficient. Your request communicates with the middleware first and then to the application in the server.

correct me if I am wrong